# Is it a good practise to share models between Microservice and Client library projects?

Tags: client, microservices

I am creating a REST microservice and a Client library for it. For both of them, I am going to use the same language (C# in this case).

Is it a good practice to share Response/Request models between those projects? Or my Client project should be independent and so have own (and actually the same) models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to share Response/Request models between ... a
>   REST microservice and a Client library?

Yes, it's a good practice. Request/response models are part of the service definition, so are one of the few things which should be shared between a service and its consumers. Vertical coupling between services and consumers is unavoidable, so should be embraced. Care should, however, be taken when sharing models between services.

> now I am confusing about the following: if another microservice will
>   use that Client library

I'm not sure what you mean - the service doesn't use the client library.

Ideally, there should be no sharing of models between services unless they are models which represent cross-cutting concerns such as security, monitoring, etc.

Comment: now I am confusing about the following: if another microservice will use that Client library, it will automatically start to use models as well -> share models...

Answer (score 0):

there might be cases when it's o.k. to share those models. In general I'd keep them separate. Models on the client don't have to worry about where data comes from and how often those models (service side) change and if that change affects them directly. Decoupling the 2 sides could make your build/deploy cycles more stable and not forcing clients to have to be rebuild whenever a service model changes etc. Also different parts of the client model may be sourcing their data from different microservices. All a matter of your overall model complexity I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No.

Long answer is the principle and purpose of the microservices architecture is to keep the service separated. So that we could gain the benefit from it (e.g. higher frequency of iteration, easier to test, lower risk of making the deployment etc)

- The service should not know other services at all. So they can use different language and tech stack. If share the model between service and consumer, it will bind the services together, make it hard to upgrade (e.g. upgrade Java version, springboot version) and lose the freedom of using different languages.
- When the service population grow, the dependencies will be very difficult to manage. Instead, we should use well defined API documents (e.g. Swagger can help use make the document always up to date), and versioning to make the API backward compatible.